# Creating animations on input texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the first sorry for my bad english, but i have a problem with animations on input texts. I just need a little help, it's almost done.
There is only one problem with which I can not cope. Just have no idea.

if you click on the email or password label animation show you the input field.
The problem is that, if we click on this same label after show the input field the animation will repeat. How to stop that, until we are clicking on label for this same input field ?

`there is a link to my code:` http://jsfiddle.net/jarzyn11/rmuL5e9o/3/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you dont use CSS instead jQuery for this?

Comment: Please post your code as well as providing a link. This keeps your question self contained in the event jsFiddle burns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used bind and unbind Jquery methods to fix the problem:

```
$(this).unbind( "click" );
....
$('#for' + $(this).attr('id')).bind( "click", function() {
    unHide($(this)) 
});
```

Hope my fix will help: http://jsfiddle.net/skymk/zwmkkx9s/